# Bootstrap radio toggle buttons checked color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to customize the colors of radio toggle buttons in bootstrap using my style.css. I can change the backgroundcolor in normal mode, but not the checked state.

I cant find any more information in the www. Do i have to use scss? The checked state should be the right one, isn't it?

Thank you very much!

```css
.showborder{
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(193, 221, 246);
}
.container{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 30vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.btn-secondary{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.btn-secondary:checked{
    background-color: crimson !important;
}
.hright{
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
        Antreibertest  
    </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app container">
            <h1>
                Willkommen zum Antreibertest!
            </h1>
            <div class="test">
                <p id="question">Question goes here</p>
                <div id="answer-buttons" class="row">
                    <input class="col btn-check" type="radio" id="r1" name="answer" value="1" autocomplete="off">  
                    <label class="col btn btn-secondary" for="r1">1</label>

                    <input class="col btn-check" type="radio" id="r2" name="answer" value="2" autocomplete="off">  
                    <label class="col btn btn-secondary" for="r2">2</label>

                    <input class="col btn-check" type="radio" id="r3" name="answer" value="3" autocomplete="off" checked >  
                    <label class="col btn btn-secondary" for="r3">3</label>

                    <input class="col btn-check" type="radio" id="r4" name="answer" value="4" autocomplete="off">  
                    <label class="col btn btn-secondary" for="r4">4</label>

                    <input class="col btn-check" type="radio" id="r5" name="answer" value="5" autocomplete="off">  
                    <label class="col btn btn-secondary" for="r5">5</label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hleft col">Trifft nicht zu</div>
                    <div class="hright col">Trifft voll zu</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="next-btn">Weiter</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-Y4oOpwW3duJdCWv5ly8SCFYWqFDsfob/3GkgExXKV4idmbt98QcxXYs9UoXAB7BZ" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you see when you inspect the element with the browser:

```
.btn-check:checked+.btn, 
.btn.active, 
.btn.show, 
.btn:first-child:active, 
:not(.btn-check)+.btn:active {
    color: var(--bs-btn-active-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-btn-active-bg);
    border-color: var(--bs-btn-active-border-color);
}
```

The relevant portion of the selector list for this situation is `.btn-check:checked+.btn`. This is a sibling selector which says *look for an element with class `btn` immediately after an element with class `btn-check` which is checked*.

You could also [override the variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/css-variables/) to apply your color globally, though.

```
:root {
  --bs-btn-active-color: orange;
  --bs-btn-active-bg;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: orange;
}
```

Note that you're actually styling the labels, not the inputs. The inputs are hidden with CSS.

Comment: how can i override the variable? i tried root:{--bs-btn-active-bg: #fff !important;} but nothing happened.

Comment: Well, it depends on how and where you tried that.

Comment: in my style.css :D where should it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css:

```
.btn-check:checked+.btn, .btn.active, .btn.show, .btn:first-child:active, :not(.btn-check)+.btn:active{
      background-color: crimson !important;

}
```